# Probelm 1.30(b) from Fulton's Algebraic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

The problem requires showing that every algebraic subset of $\mathbb{A}^{2}_{\mathbb{R}}$ is of the form $V(F)$ for some $F\in \mathbb{R}[X,Y]$.

I can prove it for all cases except when the algebraic set is a point. For $(a,b)\in \mathbb{A}^{2}_{\mathbb{R}}$, I don't see how I can find $F$ such that $V((X-a,Y-b))=V(F)$.

Maybe I am missing something obvious or maybe I have misunderstood something, so I request not to downvote the question.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is there any help from the observation that the real locus of $X^2+Y^2=0$ is just the origin?

Comment: @Lubin I see, $F=(X-a)^2+(Y-b)^2$